# TexStudio: no action on split screen

Tags: texstudio

I use texstudio 
    TeXstudio 2.11.2 (hg 6191:c01fb289a5fe)
    Using Qt Version 5.7.1, compiled with Qt 5.6.1 R

and see a menu entry when I rightclick on a file tab `split vertically` and nothing happens. If I click on `move to other view` then a split screen appears and I can see two files at once.

I assume this is intended behavior, but it seems very confusing. I would recommend to react to `split screen` with a minimal open second screen, which would then make the `move` command intuitive.

But first: is the behavior which confuses me intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of `Split Vertically` or `Split Horizontally` as a 'trigger' or an 'on/off' switch.
It doesn't actually cause the splitting, but rather, sets the direction for the splitting.
The splitting only takes effect, as you rightly pointed out, when you use the "Move to other view" options.

[image]

Whether this is intended or not, is not on-topic here (and honestly, only the devs would know.)

Recommendations for feature enhancements should go to the [project Github page](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues).